# Change Desktop filename fonts to black

Tags: font

How do I change the color of the fonts on my desktop to black? HELP has been no help. Also, on Safari, lines are so thin and light grey I can't see them; that's not good in a roadmap. I would like to change the color of the file names on desktop to black (from white) without changing anything else. I tried reversing the color and that made everything icky and dark. I calibrated the display to recommended settings but that doesn't help much; adjusting the angle of my laptop screen is no help. In Safari, I click on the top of a menu bar to drag a window and find I'm in the web address box because I can't see the border, and that triggers a menu full of icons.  Google map road lines were barely visible. The font is so fine the numbers are hard to distinguish and read. On this page, the words under the Title AskDifferent are aqua and so small and light they are barely readable. I'm sure that some of this problem is developer-based but there was a time when I could change my desktop appearance and that feature is now gone. I'm just a person who wants it the way it was before the upgrade. The 'clean' look has gone too far.

Comment: System Preferences -> Accessibility->Display: Invert Colors checkbox. Sadly, I'm sure this is not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Invert colors reverses all of the colors on the desktop, it looks real icky. I only want to change the color of my file folder names from white to black.